# How to select value if present or another if not in SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, view

I need to create a view on a SQL Server database where one of the columns may be drawn from either of two sources, depending what is present. Specifically, we have a series of tables like this (simplified):

**Table1**:

```
personid
typeid     (one of the values from Table2)
surname
forename
  etc...
```

**Table2**:

```
typeid
typename
  etc...
```

**Table3**:

```
attributeid
attributename
  etc...
```

**Table4**:

```
valueid
attributeid (one of the values from table3)
typeid      (one of the values from table2)
personid    (one of the values from table1)
attributevalue
  etc...
```

Now, I need to select (inter alia) the value of "attibutevalue" from table4 that applies to a person. This may seem straightforward (join on personid and you're done) but it's not that simple. There may be no row in Table4 with the personid, in which case we need to default to the attributevalue associated with the type. In other words, in logical terms, it's

```
if (there exists an attributevalue in t4 associated with personid) 
  use it
else 
  use attributevalue in t4 associated with typeid
```

I hope this is clear. I've been trying to work out if it could be done with some subtle joins, or coalesce, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Unfortunately I'm not much practised with SQL so some pointers would be much appreciated!

Ultimately I want t be able to write the query using the attributename in t3 (hence including it here) but for now the sticking point is just getting the right value for each attribute.

Thanks in advance

**Edit: update in response to the suggestions below** (too long for a comment!):

Thanks for your input. I've tried this but it's not returning what we expect. Here is a sample of the data:

Table1:

```
 PersonID     184
 TypeID        49
 ...etc...
```

Table4:

```
 valueid             423    424   425    426    431    432
 attributeid           4      5     6      7      6      5
 typeid               49     49    49     49     49     49
 personid           NULL   NULL  NULL   NULL    184    184
 attributevalue      yes  track    no     no    yes    pay
   etc...
```

So what we'd expect as the attribute values for person id 184 are

```
4: yes
5: pay
6: yes
7: no
```

(defaulting to the value associated with the relevant typeid where there's no value associated with a non-null personid)

Modifying the query very slightly for the sake of clarity to:

```
SELECT distinct t.id, p.AttributeID, isnull(p.attributevalue, p1.attributevalue) AS   attributevalue
    FROM table1 as T
    LEFT JOIN table4 AS p ON p.personID = t.personID
    left JOIN table4  p1 ON p1.typeID = t.typeID 
    where t.ID=184
```

We get back

```
id     AttributeID  attributevalue
184        5           pay
184        6           yes
```

So it has correctly pulled back the values where there is a personid-specific override, but not the defaults.

Any more thoughts would be much appreciated!

Thanks again

**2nd Update:**

Thanks for the suggestions here. In the end I've gone with one from elsewhere, which was to use a function and call that in each place I need to insert a value. It just returns the appropriate value for a given person/type/attribute combination. Works like a charm.

Comment: still your question is confusing. why '5:track' not in the expected resultset. It is matching againg=st type id (49).

Comment: @Sivakumar - that's because it's a type-specific default, but there's a person-specific value overriding it (valueid 432 5:pay).

Comment: I personally would redesign your database. EAV tables are extremely hard to correctly quiery and run dirt slow. If you know what attricbutes you should have in advance using an EAV table is a poor choice. If you don't know then use one but do it in a nosql database instead which is more optimized for this type of querying.

Answer (score 0):

[sql server is null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) It looks like is null is what you need, below is a demo using your demo schema.

```
SELECT isnull(p.atributeid,t.typeid) AS foo
FROM table1 as T
LEFT JOIN table4 AS p ON p.personid = t.personid
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look properly at this in the morning. First reaction: does this give us access to the value (t4.value, since edited to t4.attributevalue for clarity)? It looks at first sight to be telling us whether to use the personid or the typeid, which isn't quite what I had in mind. (I may not have fully understood...)

Comment: The left join is where the magic is happening. IF there isnt a row in in table4 that matches a row in table1 then it will return null. Since that is the case then the isnull will run like this. If Table4.atributeid is null then return table1.typeid

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for. Check this out.

```
 SELECT isnull(p.attributevalue ,p1.attributevalue) AS foo
    FROM table1 as T
    LEFT JOIN table4 AS p ON p.personid = t.personid
    LEFT JOIN table4 p1 ON p1.typeid = t.typeID
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input; I've now been able to try this but it hasn't returned quite what I'm looking for. I have edited my original query with details and example data/results. If you have further suggestions they will be much appreciated!